# Extracting the latitude and longitude substrings from the following string +25.1870+055.2784/

Tags: ios, nsstring, substring

I'm having a hard time extracting the latitude and longitude substrings from the following string +25.1870+055.2784/

Since this is a location string, the + sign could be a -. I'm looking to implement a method that would recognize a + or - sign and create the first string at the start of the second + / - sign and the second string at /.

I've posted my method below. It works perfectly but I feel it's a bit convoluted.

```
NSString *itemValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.value];
        NSLog(@"ITEM VALUE = %@", itemValue);

        NSString *firstSign = [itemValue substringToIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"FIRST SIGN = %@", firstSign);

        NSString *stringExcludingFirstSign = [itemValue substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, itemValue.length - 1)];

        NSLog(@"STRING EXCLUDING FIRST SIGN = %@", stringExcludingFirstSign);

        NSString *latitudeWithoutSign;

        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:stringExcludingFirstSign];

        if([stringExcludingFirstSign containsString:@"+"]){
            [scanner scanUpToString:@"+" intoString:&latitudeWithoutSign];
        }
        else if([stringExcludingFirstSign containsString:@"-"]){
            [scanner scanUpToString:@"-" intoString:&latitudeWithoutSign];
        }

        NSLog(@"LATITUDE WITHOUT SIGN = %@", latitudeWithoutSign);

        NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", firstSign, latitudeWithoutSign];

        NSLog(@"LATITUDE = %@", latitude);

        NSString *longitude = [itemValue substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(scanner.scanLocation + 1, (itemValue.length - (scanner.scanLocation + 1)) - 1)];

        NSLog(@"LONGITUDE = %@", longitude);
```

Comment: Have you tried `NSScanner`?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have tried NSScanner, but wasn't sure exactly how to stop scanning when the second sign is reached.

Comment: You should show that code and explain that problem

Comment: Just posted my code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your string is that you don't have any kind of separator that would indicate where the latitude / longitude is. So this is how I would approach this problem.

- What you need to do is first remove the back slash from the string. It serves no purpose
- Next replace all + or - with a space in front of them
- Since there will be a space at the very front of the string you need to remove that
- Once that is done now you use component separated by string function to separate out your long & lat.
- The lat and long are in the array. Get them and do whatever you want with them

Here is a working code that I have already tested

```
NSString *myCordStr = @"+25.1870+055.2784/";
    myCordStr=[myCordStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
    myCordStr=[myCordStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@" -"];
    myCordStr=[myCordStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" +"];

    NSString *newCordStr = [myCordStr substringFromIndex:1];

    NSLog(@"myCordStr:%@ ...", myCordStr);
    NSLog(@"newCordStr:%@ ...", newCordStr);

    NSArray *coordArray = [newCordStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"coordArray: %@ ...", coordArray);

OUTPUT:
myCordStr: +25.1870 +055.2784 ...
newCordStr:+25.1870 +055.2784 ...
coordArray: (
    "+25.1870",
    "+055.2784"
) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a bit complex, the below code does the trick.

NSString *itemValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.value];
        NSLog(@"ITEM VALUE = %@", itemValue);

```
    NSString *firstSign = [itemValue substringToIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"FIRST SIGN = %@", firstSign);

    NSString *stringExcludingFirstSign = [itemValue substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, itemValue.length - 1)];

    NSLog(@"STRING EXCLUDING FIRST SIGN = %@", stringExcludingFirstSign);

    NSString *latitudeWithoutSign;

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:stringExcludingFirstSign];

    if([stringExcludingFirstSign containsString:@"+"]){
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"+" intoString:&latitudeWithoutSign];
    }
    else if([stringExcludingFirstSign containsString:@"-"]){
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"-" intoString:&latitudeWithoutSign];
    }

    NSLog(@"LATITUDE WITHOUT SIGN = %@", latitudeWithoutSign);

    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", firstSign, latitudeWithoutSign];

    NSLog(@"LATITUDE = %@", latitude);

    NSString *longitude = [itemValue substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(scanner.scanLocation + 1, (itemValue.length - (scanner.scanLocation + 1)) - 1)];

    NSLog(@"LONGITUDE = %@", longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSRegularExpression` then use `matchesInString:options:range` to get an array of the two coordinates.

The regex would be `(+|-)\d+\.\d+`

Full code:

```
NSString *string = @"+25.1870+055.2784"
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(+|-)\d+\.\d+" options:nil error:nil]
NSArray *result = [regex matchesInString:string options:nil range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)]
```